# SQL Ranking on dynamic values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Problem statement

Create Table Code

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RankingTest

(
    DeptNo varchar(500),
    DeptName varchar (1000)
)
```

Insert Values Code

```
insert into dbo.RankingTest

SELECT 1, 'Sales'
union all
SELECT 2, 'Sales Internal'
union all
SELECT 3, 'Sales External'
union all
SELECT 4, 'Sales External IND'
union all
SELECT 5, 'Purchase'
union all
SELECT 6, 'Purchase Internal'
union all
SELECT 7, 'Purchase External'
union all
SELECT 8, 'Purchase External APC'
union all
SELECT 9, 'HR'
union all
SELECT 10, 'HR Internal'
union all
SELECT 11, 'HR External'
union all
SELECT 12, 'HR External ASA'
```

Table values with new column :

[image: Desired Output Picture]

Tried with ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK with partition by but not getting the desired result-set.
The result set is not only till 4, this is dynamic in real data scenario.
The data provided here is only for explaining the problem statement.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: As humans we can see that the first word in `DeptName` forms a significant grouping between the rows, but how would SQL Server infer that? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72884353/edit) your question to include some of the queries that you've tried.

Comment: `SELECT DeptNo, DeptName, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DeptNo) +3)%4+1 FROM yourtable;` (if you are just looking for 1-4 repeating ordered by deptno.

Comment: If you aren't looking for just 1-4 over and over again, please explain the logic that you are using to determine the ranking/row_numbering. It's not clear. Just explain it in english. Is it that a group/partition is determined by the first word in `DeptName`? Please don't update your question with just *"No it's not the first word in deptname that determines a group"*.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that you are wanting the numbering to restart with the "first" word in the DeptName column. This should ideally be another column in your table instead but you could leverage some string manipulation for this. Not sure why your DeptNo is a varchar in your sample data. But the following works for your sample data.

```
select *
    , RankValues = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by left(rt.DeptName, CHARINDEX(' ', rt.DeptName + ' ') - 1) order by rt.DeptName)
from RankingTest rt
order by try_convert(int, DeptNo)
```